# How can I let my callback function know which element of a vector called it?

Tags: c++, vector, callback

I have 2 vectors that create new buttons at random locations. The push_back is triggered by a timer. Each push_back would have a new random location and a new randval. Clicking on a button triggers cb_addscore.

```
m.push_back(new mole(Point(randx*50+25,randy*50+25),randval));
v.push_back(randval);
mb.push_back(new Button(Point(randx*50,randy*50),50,50,"1",cb_addscore));
```

In the callback function cb_addscore, I'm trying to delete the button that triggered it, which would be a specific element of the m and mb vectors.

But how can I let cb_addscore know which element triggered it?

Comment: You don't stipulate any library, and Button and Point are not C++ Standard classes.  Please stipulate your environment so the people familiar with it can help you.

Comment: It looks like he might be using fltk (Fast light toolkit). That toolkit does not use RAII, which might explain the raw `new` statements.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use an associative container instead of using a vector, and pass the additional key to the function.

You may find `std::map` useful for this task.